# Protools9 running of macbook pro icore 7 problems

Tags: software, troubleshooting, computer, pro-tools-9

I have been having trouble with my mac because it gets stuck during playback, editing or even recording, so I have to force shut down the laptop by holding the power button in! What can I do to stop this?

Comment: Does it happen only when using Pro Tools (i.e. it's not a system-wide problem)? What version of PT and have you updated it recently? What is your operating system's version and have you updated it recently? What audio interface are you using and how is it connected? Run the Apple Hardware Test and verify using Disk Utility that the disk or permissions haven't been messed up. More extensive hardware-related diagnosis can be found in e.g. Micromat TechTool.

Comment: It is only protools specific I am running version 9.0.2 mac os is 10.6.8 I havent updated it in nearly a year. I will try hardware ware test now thanks, I should probably upgrade the os hey?

Comment: I tried disk utility but it still cuts out if I run my axiom 49 and I lok (in a usb bus) and then plug my extern HD is the other available usb port on the macbook 